# Oracle Application Express - Backups

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

I have been tasked with creating some backups for some Oracle Apex apps (Application Express v4.1.1.00.23). The request is to back up both the applications & referenced db objects (not sure if this means just structure or structure & data).

On the one hand, I would have expected standard db backups to handle most or all of this but I'm very new to Apex so it's all a learning curve.

I'm currently exporting the application from apex and then exporting (using SQL Developer) all the database object dependencies that Apex gives me - although I see that the list doesn't include functions that are used for auth.

This seems a really clunky process that's very prone to mistakes (miss an object, save something to the wrong place, no guarantees of consistency etc).

Does Apex (my version!) offer something to do the job or is there something else I could be doing? I've had a good google but nothing has stood out.

UPDATE: I realise now that I should have included some extra info. I'm currently at a large organisation & I believe our db backups (which I guess/hope are done using rman) are done by a different department. I *think* the motivation for the request is so that we have some local, easily accessible backup so that if one of the developers messes something up we don't have to go through multiple layers of organisation (& undoubtedly a lot of time) to sort ourselves out. I suspect that some kind of source control would be a great starting point but I'm not sure how far I'll get with that idea - especially as we seem to have little in the way of autonomy over things like servers.

Comment: Please take care when tagging - [tag:apex] is nothing to do with [tag:oracle-apex]

Comment: Thank you for fixing the tag @TonyAndrews - that's how much I know about Oracle apex! :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found this [Oracle white paper](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/apex/learnmore/apex-life-cycle-management-wp-3030229.pdf) *Life Cycle Management with Oracle Application Express (Revision 2)* which does what it says on the tin - including various strategies for exporting, backing up & managing 'lost application development'. It's a really good read and I'll be using it as a template for suggestions of how we can manage our process in future.

Answer (score 2):

RMAN is the way to go to backup an oracle database:

https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/BRADV/toc.htm

there are tons of material on the hows and whys online; just google "oracle rman" and you'll find what you need (the documentation should cover you as well of course).

cheers

Answer (score 1):

Standard DB backups will include everything you need.

The Apex applications I develop are static, meaning the end users make no changes to the Apex application, and there is no need to make a specific backup other than to store the original apex application .sql installation files in a safe place.

If you must, you can make an export of the database schemas the application uses. For example with the expdp utility.

Answer (score 0):

IN apex you need to take 2 backups one in the workspace 
Second your application
Third is while using export import from the database  it tends to loose & character in procedure ..So beter use rman and take a complete backup.